# Jtable sorting of integer values

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable, rowsorter

I created jtable in Netbeans.

```
tableMalzeme.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
new Object [][] {
    {null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null}
},
new String [] {
    "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
}
) {
boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
    false, false, false, false
};

public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    return canEdit [columnIndex];
}
});
```

I want to sort numerically. 
Default value of "getColumnClass" is "Object" but I want to change this value.
How do you make it?

```
 tableMalzeme.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(resultSet));               
 tableMalzeme.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
 tableMalzeme.getColumnClass(0).cast(Integer.class);
```

Comment: Couldn't make meaning out of your question,SORRY! But,would you mind  helping us to understand the problem in better words!!!

Comment: what do you want to sort numerically?

Comment: I want to sort the jtable.

Comment: "setAutoCreateRowSorter" sorted as a String but I want to sort as a Integer

Answer (score 2):

> sorted as a String but I want to sort as a Integer

You need to:

1. Add `Integer` objects to the `TableModel`
2. Override the `getColumnClass(...)` class method to return `Intgeger.class` for the column that contains integers.

Comment: I can not override the "getColumnClass" using "DefaultTableModel". How can I override it using "DefaultTableModel"

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You know how to override a method of a class since you already posted code showing how you have overridden some of the method. So just add an override for the getColumnClass() method. You can read the Swing tutorial or search the forum for examples. I don't know the structure of your table so I can't tell you how to override the method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code( hope this is what you are looking for):

```
(Integer)(tableMalzeme.getColumnClass(0));
```

Comment: not sure where you would want to add that line - can't think of a suitable place (it's the model itself that must decide about its types)